# c# .Union null queryables

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
IQueryable<Container> containers1 = null;
IQueryable<Container> containers2 = null;
if (...condition1...)
{
  containers1 = containers.Where(...condition2...);
}
if (...condition3...)
{
  containers2 = containers.Where(...condition4...);
}
containers = containers1.Union(containers2);
```

In the result I need distinct list of containers, but if there is one of items is `null` it throws exception.
How can I handle `null` checking here avoiding multiple `if/else` statements?

I've tried:

```
containers = containers1.DefaultIfEmpty().Union(containers2.DefaultIfEmpty());
```

But it doesn't help, the same issue.

Comment: Don't use nulls. `null` means there's no object at all, not an empty object. You can't call methods on nothing. `IQueryable<>` isn't a container either, it's a query. You can't join the results of non-existent queries

Comment: The very fact that your **queries**, not containers, are null at the last line means your code has a serious bug and couldn't possibly produce any kind of sensible result. It's like asking you for an answer without telling you what the question is. Not even *what* kind of question - about cars? Maths? History?

Comment: So I need just set `IQueryable<Container> containers1 (and containers2) = Enumerable.Empty<Container>().AsQueryable();` instead `null`? Or what's right solution?

Comment: What is the exception and what actually is null, `containers1`/`containers2` or one of their items? The title suggests the former, the text the latter.

Comment: both can be null or one of them, what's the difference? I see ArgumentNullException

Comment: No, you need to explain what you're trying to do. `IQueryable` isn't a container, it's an interface that allows querying providers like databases, lists etc. It makes no sense to try to "instantiate" that interface. If you want to query a list or queue, you need to start from it, not an empty `IQueryable` variable

Comment: If you want to build a reusable query, create a method that expects an `IQueryable<T>` parameter, adds conditions to it and returns the last query. Use that method on the container you want. That's what `Where` and all LINQ operators do by the way

Comment: In those conditions I do something like full text search `.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Field, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")` and after that queries I do sorting, other conditions, so I don't need `.ToList()` to work with it in memory, I continue to build SQL query with linq.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, this is what you want?

```
IQueryable<Container> containers1 = null;
IQueryable<Container> containers2 = null;

containers = (containers1?.Where(...condition2...) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Container>())
    .Union(containers2?.Where(...condition4...) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Container>());
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you misunderstood what `DefaultIfEmpty()` does. It is NOT for converting null to empty enumerable. It is, like the name implies, for turning empty enumerables to ones containing just 1 item - the default, to simplify joining. See {examples from here][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=net-7.0).

What you most likely need is something along the lines of `container ?? Enumerable.Empty<TSomething>()`.

Or if you prefer fluent style, just add an extension method yourself:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NullToEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T>? items)
    => items ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

So your usage could be along the lines of:

```
containers = containers1.NullToEmpty().Union(containers2.NullToEmpty());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my question with the following way:

```
var expressions = new List<IQueryable<Container>>();
if (...condition1...)
{
  var containers1 = containers.Where(...condition2...);
  expressions.Add(containers1);
}
if (...condition3...)
{
  var containers2 = containers.Where(...condition4...);
  expressions.Add(containers2);
}
containers = expressions.Aggregate((acc, i) => acc.Union(i));
```